# React Native Maps: why are directions going off-road when origin and destination are far apart?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

I'm using `react-native-maps` and `react-native-maps-directions` in my React Native app, and the route it's drawing isn't following the streets, as shown below:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    region={{
        latitude: this.state.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: this.state.latitudeDelta,
        longitudeDelta: this.state.longitudeDelta,
    }}
>
    <MapViewDirections
        origin={origin}
        destination={destination}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY_IOS}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor='hotpink'
    />
</MapView>
```

What I notice is that this occurs when `origin` and `destination` are far apart, but not when they're close together. In the example in the image, they're about 1300km apart.

Does anyone know how I can approach fixing this?

Comment: So you provide only part of your code, and no example request? What about 1 [mcve] where is works and 1 where it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=[ORIGIN]&destination=[DESTINATION]&mode=driving&key=[YOUR API]`)
.then(res => {return res.json()})
.then(result => {
   let path = []
   result..routes[0].legs[0].steps.map(step => {
      polyline.decode(step.polyline.points).map(step => {
         path.push({latitude:step[0],longitude:step[1]})
      })
   })
   console.log(path) //You should see all of the lat & lng at this point
})

<Polyline coordinates={path} />
```

//edit stroke styles and you should see polyline, the way you want to see.

//NOTE: You need to install @mapbox/polyline using npm

Answer (score 0):

you need to add precision attribute like below.

```
    <MapViewDirections
      optimizeWaypoints={true}
      origin={origin}
      waypoints={waypoints}
      destination={dest}
      apikey={MAP_API_KEY}
      strokeColor={'hotpink'}
      strokeWidth={3}
      onReady={res => { console.log(res) }}
      precision="high"
    />
```

precision value is low by defaulte. just change it to high it will show the path on road.